# python3 can't iterate loop using data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, loops, iteration

[image: this is the data frame I work with]

Hi,

I managed to convert the table to a data frame as initialized in the picture above. I want to iterate through each row and list down all the numbers between 'start' and 'end' (of each row) including 'start' and 'end' values too.

I wrote down a code block that works when I replace 'i' with an integer. I want to iterate through all rows by using 'i' instead of an integer in a loop.

Could you please help?

I tried to adapt some solutions from StackOverflow but couldn't...

```
for i in range():
            bignumber = (df.end[i])
           while bignumber > df.start[i]:
             print(bignumber)
             bignumber = bignumber - 1
             if bignumber == df.start[i]:
                 print(bignumber.tolist())
           i=i+1
```

I tried to iterate using for loop with 'i' argument but couldn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: why not `for number in range(df.start[i], df.end[i]+1): print(number)`

Comment: you should use `.appy()` instead of `for`-loop.

Comment: if you would put small example data as text, or even better as `DataFrame(...)`, then we could simply copy it and use in solution. But now you may have to wait forever because we are too lazy to rewrite values from image. And we can only downvote and/or close question.

Answer (score 1):

You found overcomplicated code.

You can use normal `for`-loop with `range()`

```
    for number in range(row['start'], row['end']+1):
        print(number)
```

And you can use `.apply()` to run it on every `row` in `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start': [1,2,3], 
    'end':   [4,5,6], 
})

print(df)

def display(row):
    print('start:', row['start'], '| end:', row['end'])
    for number in range(row['start'], row['end']+1):
        print(number)

df.apply(display, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   start  end
0      1    4
1      2    5
2      3    6

start: 1 | end: 4
1
2
3
4
start: 2 | end: 5
2
3
4
5
start: 3 | end: 6
3
4
5
6
```

---

if you would need to iterate rows then you would use `df.iterrows()`

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print('start:', row['start'], '| end:', row['end'])
    for number in range(row['start'], row['end']+1):
        print(number)
```

but `apply` is preferred and it may work faster.